# Erro ao utilizar a biblioteca de gráficos do Google

Tags: javascript, google-charts

Estou realizando um projeto simples, onde estou usando a biblioteca do Google para trabalhar com gráficos, mas estou enfrentando um problema ao "plotar" os resultados, o seguinte erro é apresentado:

*You called the draw() method with the wrong type of data rather than a DataTable or DataView*

Código trecho do código que estou utilizando:

```js
/* variável constante */
var candidatoA = 'A';
var candidatoC = 'C';

/* variável auxiliar */
var votosCandidatoA = 0;
var votosCandidatoC = 0;

/* requisição para o biblioteca do google */
google.load("visualization", "1", { packages: ["corechart"] });
google.charts.load('current', { 'packages': ['corechart'] });
google.setOnLoadCallback(processarPopulacao);
google.setOnLoadCallback(processarAmostra);
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(graficoProporcaoVotos);

/* função para realizar o processamento dos dados de populacao */
function processarPopulacao() {
    var consultaString = encodeURIComponent('SELECT A, B, C');
    var magica = '/gviz/tq?gid=0&headers=1&tq=';
    var url = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1unuhxkhDg2qTQnhTcYmC2GkEIPM18ai8PGtSsI44Bd8';
    var query = new google.visualization.Query(url + magica + consultaString);
    query.send(consumirDadosPopulacao);
}

/* função para realizar o processamento dos dados de amostra */
function processarAmostra() {
    var consultaString = encodeURIComponent('SELECT A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K, L, M, N, O, P, Q, R, S, T, U, V, W, X, Y, Z, AA, AB, AC, AD, AE, AG');
    var magica = '/gviz/tq?gid=0&headers=1&tq=';
    var url = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1UUPbVQ6p8gOFRMznBhsxJXEUW-Axx8C2LnLKWutcL6Y';
    var query = new google.visualization.Query(url + magica + consultaString);
    query.send(consumirDadosAmostra);
}

/* função para consumir os dados de populacao */
function consumirDadosPopulacao(resposta) {
    if (resposta.isError()) {
        alert('Erro: ' + resposta.getMessage() + ' ' + resposta.getDetailedMessage());
        return;
    }
    var dados = resposta.getDataTable();
    dados.Nf.filter(function(valores) {
        proporcaoDeVotos(valores.c[2].v);
    });
    console.log("Total de votos para o candidato A: " + votosCandidatoA);
    console.log("Total de votos para o candidato C: " + votosCandidatoC);
}

/* função para consumir os dados de populacao */
function consumirDadosAmostra(resposta) {}

/* função para calcular a quantidade de votos para cada candidato */
function proporcaoDeVotos(voto) {
    if (voto == candidatoA) {
        votosCandidatoA++;
    } else {
        votosCandidatoC++;
    }
}

/* função para desenhar o gráfico de proporção de votos */
function graficoProporcaoVotos() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Candidato', 'Votos'],
        ['candidatoA', votosCandidatoA],
        ['candidatoC', votosCandidatoC]
    ]);

    var options = {
        backgroundColor: 'transparent',
    };
    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://www.google.com/jsapi" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<div id="piechart"></div>
```

O restante do código realiza uma requisição sobre os dados utilizando a api do google para acessar os dados em planilhas. É importante perceber que os dados são apresentados corretamente, ou seja, deve estar ocorrendo algum problema na hora de desenhar o gráfico.

Comment: inseri o seu código dentro do `snippe` para organizar e testar o mesmo, e está funcionando como pode verificar, como está enviando os dados dos votos para o `js` do gráfico? você está utilizando `jquery` qual versão? a `div` que irá apresentar o gráfico tem `id="piechart"`?

Comment: Vou adicionar todo o código aqui, assim fica mais simples para mostrar o problema que está ocorrendo.

Comment: Isso edite sua pergunta e insira aqui seu problema, dessa forma pode ajudar outras pessoas, links externos podem deixar de funcionar e as respostam não condizerem com o feito legal.

Comment: Adicionei todo o meu código, ele está realizando algumas requisições utilizando a biblioteca do google para planilhas, mas como você pode perceber isso não parece ser bem o problema, mas sim algo relacionado ao gráfico mesmo.

Comment: Ainda estou sem entender o problema, nesse link do *Github* que passou a uma pagina que ao acessar ela tem o resultado, que consta *58.6%* ao *CandidatoC* e *41.1%* ao *CandidatoA*, não está correto ?

Comment: Não, vou até remover o link para acessar, aquela pagina está com valores fixos, que no meu caso isso não pode ser realizado!

Comment: Na verdade eu preciso daquele script pois estou utilizando aquela biblioteca para acessar a planilha do google drive

Comment: Desculpe, eu que fiz uma confusão aqui, você quer que atualize conforme o documento é atualizado no *Drive* correto ?

Comment: Bem na verdade aquele documento não vai ocorrer mais atualizações, mas eu queria realizar o calculo dinamicamente, sem precisar colocar fixo, meu problema está na hora de desenhar o gráfico, parece que ocorre algum problema com os valores que estão nas variáveis